# IE 9, 10, 11 - Ajax calls not returning

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, internet-explorer

I am having an issue with IE related to jQuery and ajax. Chrome and Firefox work just fine, but my ajax calls are disappearing in IE.

After making the ajax call, neither the `success` nor the `fail` functions are being called. I can see the response in the IE console, and I know my controller action is being hit.

```
$.ajax({
    url: controllerUrl
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    cache: false,
    data: {
        id: customerId
    },
    success: function () {
        alert('success!');
    },
    error: function () {
        alert('failed!');
    }
});
```

Has anyone else seen this issue?

Comment: fail() is method of the promise interface: `$.ajax({...}).fail(function(){alert('failed!');});`

Comment: Are you seeing the AJAX request firing in the dev tools?  Are you sure it returns valid JSON?  Is it on the same domain?

Comment: Press F12 and read the console after refreshing the page and attempting the ajax request.

Comment: See my answer below, you're missing a comma...

Answer (score 2):

```
fail: function () {
        alert('failed!');
    }
```

`fail` is not a valid jQuery ajax setting. I believe you are looking for `error`.

Also, `cache: false,` does nothing with `POST` requests.

Note, jQuery *does not* append the time stamp with `POST` requests.

The source code clearly demonstrates this. (summarized from https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/ajax.js)

```
var rnoContent = /^(?:GET|HEAD)$/;
s.hasContent = !rnoContent.test( s.type );
if ( !s.hasContent ) {
   /* code to append time stamp */
}
```

Comment: `cache: false` does do something on posts... it appends a timestamp as a URL parameter

Comment: @FastTrack How sure are you of that? =)

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/: `Setting cache to false will only work correctly with HEAD and GET requests ... The parameter is not needed for other types of requests, except in IE8 when a POST is made to a URL that has already been requested by a GET.`

Comment: @BradM Thanks, but that still doesnt fix my problem, the `error` function still doesnt get called...

Comment: Also, I *highly* suggest logging the parameters sent to `error` not just alerting 'failed'.  `error: function(jqXHR, status, error){ console.log(status,error); }`

Comment: @BradM `cache` may not be NEEDED, but it does DO something... Try it out for yourself. It will append a URL parameter: `_` with the current timestamp.

Comment: @FastTrack `$.ajax({type: 'POST', cache: false});` Look at the request. Lol, it is you who needs to try it for yourself.

Comment: @BradM I just did... using `cache: false` appends a `_` parameter with a timestamp to `POST` and `GET` calls (although not _needed_ for `POST`). Using `cache: true` does not append this URL parameter. Regardless, his problem is due to a missing comma - see my answer

Comment: @FastTrack I posted code from jQuery source proving you wrong. You just got internet pwnd. Can you please stop attacking me now? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a comma `,` after your URL parameter:

```
$.ajax({
    url: controllerUrl, // <--- you were missing this comma!
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    cache: false,
    data: {
        id: customerId
    },
    success: function () {
        alert('success!');
    },
    error: function () {
        alert('failed!');
    }
});
```

Comment: If that first comma was missing, it wouldn't work it *any* browser.

Comment: @BradM that is absolutely NOT true. I've seen this MANY times before with multiple AJAX calls.

Comment: Yes, he needs the comma there, but without it, it would crash in **every. single.  browser.**

Comment: @RocketHazmat you are correct. Not sure how it's working for him in Firefox/Chrome then

Comment: @FastTrack: Maybe the lack of comma was just a typo in the question and not his real code ;)